# Dynamic textarea Size on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, x-editable

I am currently using [X-Editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) to have text input areas. With X-Editable, you choose a static textarea size. I am trying to make this dynamic because some areas are just one word, but others are paragraphs. I have been able to get the text area to resize automatically on 'keyup' but not when the textarea is created. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="recharge-info">
 <div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="general-tab">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="general-info" class="info-tabs">
      <p>Name: <span id="recharge-name" class="info general edit"></span></p>
      <p>Department: <span id="recharge-dept" class="info general edit"></span></p>
      <p>Category: <span id="recharge-cat" class="info general edit"></span></p>
      <p>Location: <span id="recharge-loc" class="info general edit"></span></p>
      <p>Status: <span id="recharge-status" class="info general edit"></span></p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
//This is the part im having trouble with. When clicking on the 'p' to create the textarea, it is not creating the text area the right size.
$('#recharge-info p').on( 'click', function (e){
    $('#recharge-info textarea').css('height', 'auto' );
    $('#recharge-info textarea').height( $('#recharge-info textarea').prop('scrollHeight') );
    console.log($('#recharge-info textarea').prop('scrollHeight'));
});

//This part, on keyup works no problem. When im in the text area and type, it auto resizes correctly and works great.
$('#recharge-info').on( 'keyup', 'textarea', function (e){
    $(this).css('height', 'auto' );
    $(this).height( this.scrollHeight );
});
$('#recharge-info').find( 'textarea' ).keyup();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance